# count pages round up PHP

Tags: php

i've got a album site for photos but i want to count the amount of photos from the Database with the amount of images each page can be changed by Admin in PHP.

**PHP Code**

```
<a href="albumview.php?ID='. $_GET['ID'].'&page='. round((count($view) / $photoselect)) .'"><button>Last page</button></a>
```

> count($view) = 5
>
> count($view) = 4

so he counts *1.25* and goes to page 1 as last page. but on page 2 is still one photo. so the last page is 2.

in an other example i got

> count($view) = 20
>
> count($view) = 4

Then he is going to page 5 correctly because it is rounded to the good amount.
Anyone knows a function?

Comment: in the example which doesn't work, what did you want it to do instead?

Comment: yeah it is in an echo don't worry 'bout that, the question is in the example he counts 5/4= 1.25 and then he goes to albumview.php?ID=86&page=1 and not the last page (2) edit the SECOND example works because it is a round number.

Comment: ceil() does work for me Thanks guys! instead of 1.25 he is going to 2 now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figuring out paging is relatively simple.

Imagine you have 42 records, and display ten per page.

```
$numPerPage = 10; // this is your limit clause in sql
$page = $_GET['page'] ?: 1; // default to 1 if not set.
$offset = ($page * $numPerPage) - $numPerpage;
$totalPages = ceil($numRecords / $numPerPage);
```

- Offset eg page 3 = (10 * 3) - 10; // offset 20
- TotalPages eg 42/10 = 4.2, ceiling makes it 5

So then in your SQL:

```
SELECT xFROM y WHERE z='a' OFFSET $offset LIMIT $numPerPage
```

Comment: Yes thank the ceil one did it for me! this is a great example!

Comment: Glad I could help!